# Printing Column

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm having a problem printing columns. When the code reaches "100" it stops reading what is below it because it's empty:

```
public class Column{

  public static void main( String[] arg )
  {

    int[][] uneven = 
        { { 1, 3, 100, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
          { 0, 2},
          { 0, 2, 4, 5},
          { 0, 2, 4, 6, 7},
          { 0, 1, 4, 5 },
          { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }};

    for ( int col=0; col < uneven.length; col++ )
    {
      System.out.print("Col " + col + ": ");
      for( int row=0; row < uneven.length; row++ ) 
        System.out.print( uneven[row][col] + " ");
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

What should I do so that it will continue reading the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print a variable length 2-D array, your inner loop runs from `0` to `the current row` length : -

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {  // Closely see inner loop

        System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

`arr[i]` is the current row. And `arr[i].length` gives the number of columns in that row.

**You can infer it like this: -**

- `arr` is a 2-D array.
- So, each element of your `arr` is a `1-D array`.
- So, `arr[i]` is a 1-D array. Which represents each row.
- To get number of columns in each row, you do `arr[i].length`

Now, you can apply the same thing in your problem.

---

Actually, your `for loop` is running wrongly. Your `outer loop` is running from `col = 0 to col < uneven.length`, but it should run from: - `row = 0 to row < uneven.length`

So, your for loop should be like: -

```
for ( int row=0; row < uneven.length; row++ )
{
   System.out.print("Row " + row + ": ");

   for( int col=0; col < uneven[row].length; col++ ) { 
     System.out.print( uneven[row][col] + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

---

### UPDATED : -

Ok, I got your question wrong first. If you want to print `column wise`, you can use this code: -

```
int[][] uneven = 
    { { 1, 3, 100, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
      { 0, 2},
      { 0, 2, 4, 5},
      { 0, 2, 4, 6, 7},
      { 0, 1, 4, 5 },
      { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }};

    int max = -1;
    for ( int row = 0; row < uneven.length; row++ ) {
        if (uneven[row].length > max) {
            max = uneven[row].length;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < uneven.length; j++) {
            if (uneven[j].length <= i) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print(uneven[j][i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

First you need to find the max among all number of columns in each row.

Then run the loop again, from 0 to max columns. Now, since you have a lop for `columns`, now you need another one for `rows`. And that will be your inner loop.

Now, in inner loop, you cannot just print the array element at the `(j, i)` index, because the current row might not have `max` number of columns. So, you need to put an `if-condition` to check that.

Comment: my problem is "HOW TO PRINT THE "COLUMN" "
not printing the row sir :))

Comment: For that you would have to do some work. First you need to know the maximum length column among all the rows.

Comment: Your program Prints the row sir :(

Comment: @ChrisValenzuela His code works perfectly fine. Look at the bottom of his post, he added the correct program. Just ran it, works like a charm.

Comment: FORGOT TO REFRESH MY PAGE DIDNT SEE THAT CODES -__-"
THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR... MY PROGRAM IS RUNNING PERFECTLY
I MEAN YOUR PROGRAM :)
I need to learn more :)
im just a 19yrs old student >.<

Comment: @ChrisValenzuela being 19 doesn't give you the right to use caps lock. :P

Comment: @ChrisValenzuela.. You're welcome :) And sure you will learn quickly if you keep on trying your problems yourselves just as now. Best of Luck :)

Comment: @ChrisValenzuela.. No offend taken. Keep Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
for( int row=0; row < uneven.length; row++ )
```

with:

```
for( int row=0; row < uneven[col].length; row++ )
```

Comment: made my program more worst :(

Comment: your loop composition is different. Do you want to display the items column by column?

Comment: yeah but when it reaches "100" it stops....
I want to print it column by column..

Comment: OK. I misunderstood your question. Since you got the answer above, it's done :)